# Simple ocaml code didn't work

Tags: ocaml

I have a simple code in Ocaml described below:

```
for i = 1 to 9 do
  for j = 1 to 9 do
    let k = i*10+j
    Format. printf "(define x%d :: int)@." k
  done;
  print_newline ()
done
```

But it results in a syntax error, and I don't know why:

```
File "main.ml", line 5, characters 2-6: Error: Syntax error --> Line 5: done;
```

Please help me fix it and recommend me a good book to learn Ocaml. I am a newbie, so confused about everything in it. Ocaml is completely different with C++.

Thank you so much

Comment: Define "didn't work"

Comment: File "main.ml", line 5, characters 2-6:
Error: Syntax error
--> Line 5: done;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have forgotten `in` on the third line.

You can find a lot of sources about OCaml, including good books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ocaml/info).

### Update

```
for i = 1 to 9 do
  for j = 1 to 9 do
    let k = i * 10 + j in (* <- syntax requires you to put `in` here *)
    Format.printf "(define x%d :: int)@." k
  done;
  print_newline ()
done
```

There are two kinds of let bindings in OCaml:

1. toplevel binding, that can occur inside the module definitions and toplevel, it has a form of `let <name> = <expr>`
2. expression binding, that can occur inside other expressions, including functions, it has form of `let <name> = <expr-1> in <expr-2>`, and it creates a binding between `<name>` and `<expr-1>` that works in the scope of `<expr-2>`, where binding is an association between a name and a value, and scope is a lexical part of code (i.e., part of code that is occupied by `<expr-2>`).

Anyway, it is hard to explain OCaml in two sentences, so consider reading OCaml books, that are written by much more experienced teachers, than I am))

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you help me fix it ?

Comment: I've elaborated the answer, hope that this will help